# N QUEENS problems

Tags: c

I try to solve the problem of N queens solution and manage to create an algorithm that gives me all possibilities and prints it (I try to understand everything but as backtracking is a little new to me, it is hard).

My program looks at every possibility and prints the position of the queens one by colones, it looks like it works well, even if I don't understand my stopping condition.

My problem is that I need to print the position in a certain a order (start from first queen position 0 - N), but it prints in a random way.

I could store it in an array and sort it, but it will take too much time, so i would like to know if people can look at my code and point out possible problems and give some tips or feedback.

```
#include <unistd.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
#define N 10

  void  print(int tab[N][N])
 {
   int i;
   int a;
   char c;

    i = -1;
    while (++i < N)
    {
    a = -1;
    while (++a < N)
        if (tab[a][i])
        {
            c = '0' + a;
            write(1, &c, 1);
        }
     }
     write(1, "\n", 1);
 }


   int  check(int tab[N][N] , int x, int y)
   {
      int i;
      int j;

      i = 0;
      while (i < x)
       if (tab[i++][y])
          return (0);
      i = x;
      j = y;
      while (j >= 0 && i >= 0)
       if (tab[i--][j--])
          return (0);
      i = x;
      j = y;
      while (i >= 0 && j < N)
        if (tab[i--][j++])
          return (0);
     return (1);
    }


    int     backtrack(int tab[N][N],int x ,int y, int *nbr)
    {
       if (x >= N)
       {
          print(tab);
          *nbr += 1;
       }
       while (++y < N)
         if (check(tab, x, y))
         {
              tab[x][y] = 1;
              if (backtrack(tab, x + 1, -1, nbr))
                  return (1);
              tab[x][y] = 0;
         }
       return (0);
    }


    int     ft_ten_queens_puzzle(void)
    {
       int tab[N][N];
       int nbr;
       int b;

       nbr = -1;
       while(++nbr < N)
       {
          b = -1;
          while (++b < N)
           tab[nbr][b] = 0;
       }
       nbr = 0;
       backtrack(tab,0,-1, &nbr);
       return (nbr);
    }

    int main()
    { 
             printf("%d\n",ft_ten_queens_puzzle());
     }
```

Comment: Where's the main? We cannot compile this code!

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `write` instead of stdio (e.g., `putc`)?

Comment: yeah it for the exercise i can only use write function only @Arkku, you can just put ft_ten_queens_puzzle in a main to test it , it don t need any value in entry

Comment: How are you expecting us to evaluate your code, when it does not cleanly compile?  Please post a [mcve].   Are you expecting us to guess the contents of the missing part(s) of the code?

Comment: This is all my code , I don't have missing part , except for the main that should look like int main()   { ft_ten_queens_puzzle();}

Answer (score 3):

Your output is coming out random due to a couple of bugs in your `print` function :

a) If you are printing out a grid, then EVERY cell must be output, but you are not printing cells where `tab[a][i]` is 0

b) You need a newline at the end of EVERY line, but your write statement is in the wrong place

So the function should be like :

```
void  print(int tab[N][N])
{
   char c;

   for (int i=0; i < N; i++)
   {
      for (int a=0; a < N; a++)
      {
         if (tab[a][i])
         {
            c = '0' + a;
         }
         else 
         {
             c = ' ';
         }
         write(1, &c, 1);
     }
     write(1, "\n", 1);
   }
}
```

A couple of tips/feedback :

- Use full easy-to-understand variable names.
- Don't use that awkward "int x = -1;  while (++x < N) {" format - the standard `for (int x=0; x < N; x++) {` format is better
- Indent your code correctly. for example, in `print`, you had the write for the newline out side of it's intended loop, which was easily missed due to indentation issues
- Yes, the language allows you to skip the "{","}" for single-statement loops and `if` statements.  I would STRONGLY recommend to never skip them, but always put them on all loops and `if`s; It is so much easier to both prevent, and also to track down bugs (especially when indentation is not consistent)

Just my thoughts, I hope they help :)

Comment: thanks you for your reply ,
for this exercise i don't need to print the grill completely , only the potision of the queen on each colone should be printed , so i print one line of solution after another and not the full grill 
i cannot use 'for ' loop for this exercise.
thanks you for your tip and your time i mush appreciet it :)